# Change URL of the twitter 'share button'

Tags: html, url, twitter

I want to add a `URL` to a Twitter "share button" which points to a section of the target page.

I am using this code:

```
<div>
<a class="twitter-share-button" href="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=The process...random text. mezet.xyz/dl18/manifesto/#section" data-size="large">
Tweet</a>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: click on the twitter post, it wil open as a new pop up window, copy the url you see in the domain bar, and paste it in the `href` tag.

Comment: On image you see this link: mezet.xyz/dl18/manifesto/, I want to change it to  mezet.xyz/dl18/manifesto/#section1. I am ot sure how to do it inside link I see in a popup

Comment: `#section1` means you want it to go to an `id` tag of that page link. you could do that if the `id`= `section1` is available ? im not sure if I am understanding 100% correct

Comment: if i click on that link `mezet.xyz/dl18/manifesto/` it takes me to a page without an tag `ID` called `section1` , so lets say you want the user to see `Our Priorities`  the url wil look like this `http://mezet.xyz/dl18/manifesto/#priorities-section` as it points to the `id` in the `div` called `priorities-section`

Comment: Yes, I put section1 as an example. And yes, I want that link with IDs to be shown inside tweet. But, I don't know which attr or what should I add o my code to make it replace current url shown in tweet.

Comment: u will have to edit the twitter post on Twitter it self , you cant change the text(`url`) of the tweet within the `div` `a` tag.

Comment: Yes, Thank you. I found several answers but they were from 2012 or 2013. I thought things might have been changed. Is there other solution I can implement to  share tweet with custom URL. Maybe with JS or something.

Comment: well a work around might be adding an `a` tag around the `div` that points to `http://mezet.xyz/dl18/manifesto/#section1` , remember to add `style="display:block"` to the `div` else it wont wrap correctly. But changing the text of the tweet i cant help you with.

Comment: I will give it a try. Thank you very much. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope it is what you where looking for. If you want to post a tweet with an `url` to take you to a certain section of the page linking an `id` , for twiiter you cant use `#` in the `url`, manipulating the # tag use the following.

Add : **%23** as an **#** tag

```html
<div>   
    <a class="twitter-share-button" href="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=The process...of this is just total dummy text to test if i can manupilate the url. http://mezet.xyz/dl18/manifesto/%23priorities-section " data-size="large">Tweet</a>
</div>
```

Run code snippt, right click on "Tweet" and `open link in new tab`. You will see the URL with the # tag added.

Comment: I get this result : The process...of this is just total dummy text to test if i can manupilate the url. http://mezet.xyz/dl18/manifesto/#priorities-section … http://mezet.xyz/dl18/manifesto/
It shares both urls. I get the same resulr this by adding url insisde tweet?text.

Comment: if you use it as my code snippet , you click the tweet `a` tag text you wil see the post with the `url` after the text snippet , if you tweet that and click on the link, it should take you to ` http://mezet.xyz/dl18/manifesto/#priorities-section`

Comment: forget about the a tag around the div , just manipilate the url # tag using `%23`

Comment: if i look at your tweet activity looks like it worked?